# Can I use a 4 quart crock pot instead of a 6 quart?

Tags: crockpot

For a recipe that calls for a 6 quart crock pot, can I use a four quart crock pot?  Should I only use 2/3 of each ingredient?

Comment: That will depend on the total volume of the ingredients, and the type of ingredients. For example, if you were making a 3 quart water based soup, it would be fine, but if you were boiling something with milk or cream, you might have to worry more about overflow. Can you tell us more about the recipe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use a larger crockpot than the recipe calls for?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15231/can-i-use-a-larger-crockpot-than-the-recipe-calls-for)

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered very few recipes that can't be scaled. In fact the only recipes I can think of are jelly because the pectin behaves oddly.

If the scaled recipe fits comfortably then you are fine.

Keep in mind that a smaller volume may cook faster. This shouldn't be a problem for most slow cooker recipes but use your judgement. If you are braising a pot roast then a bit too long won't hurt much. If you are cooking peach cobbler it might need to finish earlier.