# Can I use a larger crockpot than the recipe calls for?

Tags: equipment, slow-cooking, crockpot

I have a recipe that calls for use of a 4 qt crockpot. However, I only have a 6 qt. Is it okay to use the 6 qt instead? The recipe is for a pudding cake.

Comment: @hobodave This question is the opposite of the duplicate you picked. I think "Can I use a larger crockpot than called for" is different from "Can I use a smaller crockpot than called for".

Comment: I also disagree with the closing. I think there are some good answers available here about not only scaling recipes, but also about how to deal with excessive evaporation, etc., when your recipe is significantly smaller than your crockpot.

Comment: I agree.  I didn't spot the difference right away either, but it is in fact a different question.  I would *prefer* to see one comprehensive answer about crockpot scaling in general, and then we can merge the two questions (they are honestly very hard to tell apart, despite not being exact duplicates).

Answer (score 2):

If you keep the lid on, it shouldn't make much difference in practice.

The thing to watch is that the larger surface area and heat supply of the 6 qt pot might make the recipe cook a little quicker than it would in a 4 qt pot, and also make it dry out quicker than it should (which is why you need the lid on). Just take a look after about two thirds of the time and decide if you should add a little water, or not.